# Can Visual Studio Code stop files from being deleted

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am working with visual studio code to write up some `terraform`.

the source is under git for source control, and I have an ignore set for `*.tfvars*`

When I reset the branch I have to have the tfvars file open and see it flag as `(deleted)`.

I am wondering if VSCode, can be told to hold the tfvars file, so when I reset my branch it will not delete the file?

I'm thinking that I will need to be looking at something in the setup for VSCode itself, so am starting there.

Comment: If you don't want to delete the file, why are you ignoring it?
If you don't want to keep the file in git, then just move the file elsewhere and reference the file in your code

Comment: Thanks for the reply I know that is an option, I was wondering if there is anything built into vscode, I have heard that there are some other IDEs that will let you.